# My post was deleted and I don't know what was wrong with it

Tags: support

I have a question about my Ask Ubuntu post: [Under Ubuntu 18.04 my Java 10 application doesn't scale with the screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034121/under-ubuntu-18-04-my-java-10-application-doesnt-scale-with-the-screen/1323523#1323523)

Why was my post deleted? No reason is given as far as I can see. What's wrong with the (related) question?

Answer (score 9):

I'm the one who deleted your question.

As already someone in the comments has pointed out, you should post your problem as a [new question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) and not an answer to another question. AskUbuntu is a Q/A website and not a forum.

> Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum. Most forums are largely discussion-based and tend to follow less strict rules about what posts can be like.
> On Stack Overflow (and Stack Exchange in general), we require every new thread to be started with a question and every response to that question to be an attempt at answering it.

from [Are Stack Exchange sites forums?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums)

You might also want to take the [tour](https://askubuntu.com/tour).

Answer (score 4):

Ask Ubuntu or any other site on Stack Exchange network is based on Q&A model and your question was posted in answer section.

[Thunderbird](https://askubuntu.com/users/531149) left [a similar comment](https://askubuntu.com/posts/comments/2255792) on your post.

If you have any question please post that using [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button and provide the link to the already existing post(s) only if they provide any context. For more visit [help center](https://askubuntu.com/help).